# how to compare three strings using strig.compare in c#.net?

Tags: c#

I want to compare three or more strings, as follows

```
using System;

namespace StringApplication
{
   class StringProg
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string str1 = "This is test";
         string str2 = "This is text";
         string str3 = "This is text";

         if (String.Compare(str1, str2,str3) == 0)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(str1 + " and " + str2 +  " are equal.");
         }
         else
         {
            Console.WriteLine(str1 + " and " + str2 + " are not equal.");
         }
         Console.ReadKey() ;
      }
   }
}
```

But I get an error.

Comment: you can't compare 3 strings. you have to compare pairs of them.

Comment: What should be the result of such a comparison? `str1 > str2 < str3`? An ordered string? All are equal/at least one has different value than the other two?...

Comment: `bool allEqual = !new string[]{str1,str2,str3}.Distinct().Skip(1).Any();`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am amused.

Comment: Tim's answer is good enough for an unknown number of strings, but a little wasteful in this example. +1 for flippancy though ;-)

Comment: Or `var conc = new[] { "a", "a", "a" };
                return conc.Zip(conc.Reverse().Take(1).Concat(conc.Take(conc.Length - 1)), (s, s1) => s.Equals(s1)).All(res => res);`

Comment: than u for all of u.....now i understand that we can't compare 3 string at a time ........by comparing each with others i gt solution....

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i can't understand ur thing.....pls ...explain....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Compares **two specified String** objects and returns an integer that
>   indicates their relative position in the sort order. This member is
>   overloaded. For complete information about this member, including
>   syntax, usage, and examples, click a name in the overload list.

hence you cannot compare three string this way. Instead of doing this, you could try the following, *if you want to compare all the three strings, which I assume is that you want*:

```
if (String.Compare(str1, str2) == 0 &&  
    String.Compare(str2, str3) == 0)
```

Comment: If String 1 and 2 Are equal and 1 and 3 are equal, 2 and 3 must be equal, so you dont need the last Logic check surely?

Comment: Oops you are correct...foolish...Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it manually. Compare the first with the second, than the first with the third, the first with the forth etc. If the current pair under test is not equal, you can immediately conclude the whole set is not equal. If all pairs are reported as equal, they are all equal.